# jQuery toggle();

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am loading data dynamically by AJAX into a cluetip (http://plugins.learningjquery.com/cluetip/#).

I want to toggle the results from a link like so:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#calendarLink").live("click",( function() {
        $("#result").toggle();
    }));
});
```

For some reason the above will not work. Can you suggest an alternative?

Answer (score 1):

Couple of questions/points

Do you really need to use `.live()` You're using an ID selector, so there should only ever be one of these.

Also, you have an extra set of brakets. Probably not a problem, but you could remove them:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#calendarLink").click( function() {
        $("#result").toggle();
    });
});
```

Comment: Tried the code but get same result. Toggle not working very strange.

Comment: Suppose I don’t need the .live function but either way it doesn’t work

Comment: Can you post your HTML as well, and add a comment below when you've done this so it shows up for me.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the toggle() function isn't be used properly?

See here http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

I'm not sure if this is new functionality only for jQuery 1.4 but it appears the toggle function requires parameters.

Answer (score 0):

The following code is correct (demo online - http://jsbin.com/ehate/edit):

```
$("#calendarLink").live("click", function(e){
  $("#result").toggle();
});
```

You use `$.live()` only if `#calendarLink` will be added dynamically later. If it isn't, use a regular click:

```
$("#calendarLink").click(function(e){
  $("#result").toggle();
});
```

If this is not working for you, be sure to check your `#calendarLink` and `#result` elements in your HTML. Make sure the ID values are correct. Mainly, be sure your casing is correct.

Comment: shouldn't the '#result' be changed to '.result'? I added an answer

Answer (score 0):

Two elements in the same page can't have the same id.

u used

```
$("#result").toggle();
```

'I want to toggle the results from a link ...'

So the result elements should have the same class , not id.

The code should be :

```
$(".result").toggle();
```

'#' changed into '.'